# boto3 ConnectionClosedError python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, chalice

I am trying to deploy Rest Api with Chalice.
When I do chalice deploy.

The code worked with chalice local. But it fails in Deployment.

I get the following error:

```
Creating deployment package.
Updating policy for IAM role: learnChalice-dev
Updating lambda function: learnChalice-dev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 92, in _send_request
    method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 119, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 203, in send
    return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1003, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
socket.timeout: The write operation timed out
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 263, in send
    chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 344, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 92, in _send_request
    method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 119, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 203, in send
    return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1003, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/cli/__init__.py", line 599, in main
    return cli(obj={})
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
```

```
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
```

File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/cli/**init**.py", line 206, in deploy
    deployed_values = d.deploy(config, chalice_stage_name=stage)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/deploy/deployer.py", line 353, in deploy
    return self._deploy(config, chalice_stage_name)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/deploy/deployer.py", line 366, in _deploy
    self._executor.execute(plan)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/deploy/executor.py", line 44, in execute
    self._default_handler)(instruction)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/deploy/executor.py", line 56, in _do_apicall
    result = method(**final_kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/awsclient.py", line 273, in update_function
    zip_contents=zip_contents)

```
  File "/home/dragon/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chalice/awsclient.py", line 294, in _update_function_code
    FunctionName=function_name, ZipFile=zip_contents)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 613, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 632, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 231, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 244, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/home/dragon/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 294, in send
    endpoint_url=request.url
botocore.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/learnChalice-dev/code".
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: There is some timeout. Can you verify that you can connect to deploy test lambda functions from AWS CLI manually (no chalice), or `invoke` them?

Comment: Hey @Marcin ,, I was able to do till few hours back. 
I just added a little extra code. Using web3.py now. 

IDK how to deploy with just aws cli ..to lambda.. ok will check

Comment: Hey @Marcin I also tried this. https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/344
Increased the default timeout in botocore/endpoint.py - 60 , 120 , 500, etc. Nothing worked.

Comment: Do you run this from your local workstation or some ec2 instance on aws?

Comment: I am working in local only.

Comment: do you have aws cli setup? Can just try something basic, like `aws s3 ls`, just to check if you have conectivity to aws.

Comment: Yeah I have that, `aws s3 ls
2020-05-27 03:12:05 storage-1
2020-05-13 00:11:40 amplify-app-first-01131-deployment
`

Comment: that's good. thus it maybe chalice related issue.

Comment: So, What should I do @Marcin

Comment: I'm not too familar with chalice. Just wanted to check the basic thing regarding the timeout. Sorry.

Comment: Ok,, thanks a lot.. @Marcin
But what can be the error?

Comment: You have the error `The write operation timed out`. Have to identify where is this time out comming from. Maybe your deployment package is too big as written [here](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/330)?

Comment: Yes the size must be a cause.

Comment: Do you know how big your package is?

Comment: When I was ziping it.. the size became 40 MB when only one python code is there and requirements.txt

Comment: Maybe its very slow upload. Have you tried increasing time `chalice deploy --botocore-timeout 300` or more?

Comment: I tried this command .. chalice deploy doesnt have that option

Comment: I also tried this. github.com/aws/chalice/issues/344 Increased the default timeout in botocore/endpoint.py - 60 , 120 , 500, etc. Nothing worked

Comment: try `--connection-timeout 300`

Comment: awesome .. it worked ..

Comment: Cool. I will make answer then for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution was to increase default timeout:

```
chalice deploy --connection-timeout 300
```